# JAVA/Oracle SQL Hanging Due to Blockage

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle11g

I am creating an Elo system for a betting program I am creating to compare two competitors and determine the amount to bet.  I have gathered some data overtime and need to put all of this data through a calculation to gather the Elo score.

I have about 1150 records to do this to.  My initial method was to query all of the records and then, by using a while(rs.next()), go put each record through the calculation and then update the table with the new values with another query.  But the program hangs on my update statement.  The location in which it hangs is marked with the comment "//HANGS RIGHT HERE" in the code below.  The funny thing is, it does not give any error or exception.  It just sits there an will not progress any further.  I have tried several solutions and cannot come up / research a solution.  The below code represents the program in its entirety:

```
package elomaker;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EloMaker {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    //initial variables
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Component frame = null;
    String sqlPullFights = "select  f.fid,\n"
            + "        f.p1id,\n"
            + "        f.p2id,\n"
            + "        f.winner,\n"
            + "        (select p.elo from players p where f.p1id = p.pid) p1elo,\n"
            + "        (select pl.elo from players pl where f.p2id = pl.pid) p2elo\n"
            + "from    fights f";
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int x = 0;

    //initializing the database to make sure the datbase is ready.
    String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
    String userName = "NEGGLY";
    String password = "Yellow23";
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, userName, password);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't register JDBC driver,");
        System.out.println("Applicaiton Ending.");
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Could not establish a connection to the database", "Database Error", +JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    //pull the fight values for each player
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlPullFights);
    while (rs.next()) {
        int intP1ID = rs.getInt("P1ID");
        int intP2ID = rs.getInt("P2ID");
        int intWinner = rs.getInt("WINNER");
        int intP1Elo = rs.getInt("P1ELO");
        int intP2Elo = rs.getInt("P2ELO");
        int intP1NewRating, intP2NewRating;
        double dblP1Outcome, dblP2Outcome;

        dblP1Outcome = 1 / (1 + (Math.pow(10, (intP2Elo - intP1Elo) / 400)));
        dblP2Outcome = 1 - dblP1Outcome;

        //determine the winner
        if (intP1ID == intWinner) {
            intP1NewRating = (int) (intP1Elo + 32 * (1-dblP1Outcome));
            intP2NewRating = (int) (intP2Elo + 32 * (0-dblP2Outcome));
        } else {
            intP2NewRating = (int) (intP2Elo + 32 * (1-dblP2Outcome));
            intP1NewRating = (int) (intP1Elo + 32 * (0-dblP1Outcome));
        }

        String sqlUpdP1Rate = "update players set elo = "+intP1NewRating+" where pid = " + intP1ID;
        String sqlUpdP2Rate = "update players set elo = "+intP2NewRating+" where pid = " + intP2ID;

        stmt.executeQuery(sqlUpdP1Rate); //HANGS RIGHT HERE.
        stmt.executeQuery(sqlUpdP2Rate);
        stmt.executeQuery("commit");

        x++;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

}

}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to add `con.setAutoCommit(true);` instead of calling `commit` explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a classical deadlock here:

1. you fetch a list of matches and the ELO rating for each of the participants in the match
2. for each of these matches

   2.1 you compute the outcome for each participant

   2.2 you update the rating for each of the participants

But what should Oracle do in 2.2? Should it automagically change the result set you fetched in 1. (and that you're currently iterating over) to reflect the updated ratings? Or should it keep the old ratings, which would lead to bogus results if one player participated in more than one match?

So, I'd suggest you modify your approach to:

- fetch the results of your query into an array or similar
- iterate over this list
- keep your computation + update logic as it is

This should get rid of the deadlock (sorry, I'm not an JDBC expert, so I cannot provide you with an example of how to achieve this).

Comment: I did end up creating a new statement instead.

Comment: After some time of thinking, this ended up being the best approach in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

When application gets blocked execute this query:

```
select /* +rule */
  s1.username || '@' || s1.machine
    || ' ( SID=' || s1.sid || ' ' || s1.program || ' )  is blocking ' 
    || s2.username || '@' || s2.machine || ' ( SID=' || s2.sid || ' ' || s2.program 
    || ' ) ' AS blocking_status
from v$lock l1, v$session s1, v$lock l2, v$session s2
where s1.sid=l1.sid and s2.sid=l2.sid
and l1.BLOCK=1 and l2.request > 0
and l1.id1 = l2.id1
and l2.id2 = l2.id2 ;
```

This will tell you which session is holdig the lock you're waiting for.

PS: maybe use `con.commit();` to commit your transaction. You also should not *fetch across commit*. Put the commit at very end of your script(youtside the loop). But anyway I think that JDBC connections have autocommit enabled by default (try to turn it off).

Comment: It did turn out that my own SQL Developer was causing part of my blocking.  Thanks to this script, it just pointed straight to the blocking program.